# Does sequence almost sure convergence imply almost sure convergence?

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

This is a cross-post of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2801027/64809) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2800921/64809) questions from math.stackexchange.com since I have not received any response there. I would like to seek help here.

Suppose $x(t,\omega): [0,T]\times\Omega\rightarrow \mathbf R$ is a random variable on a probability space $\Omega$.

1. Sequence $(t_k<2^{-k})_{k=1}^\infty \implies \lim_\limits{i\rightarrow\infty}x(t_i,\omega)\rightarrow0$ for almost all $\omega\in\Omega$. Does this imply $\lim_\limits{t\rightarrow0}x(t,\omega)=0$ for almost all $\omega\in\Omega$? What if we assume $\lim_\limits{t\rightarrow0}x(t,\omega)=0$ in probability?
2. For every sequence $(t_k)_{k=1}^\infty\rightarrow 0$, $\exists$ a subsequence $(t_{k_i})_{i=1}^\infty$ independent of $\omega$  $\ni\big(\lim_\limits{i\rightarrow\infty}x(t_i,\omega)\rightarrow0$ for almost all $\omega\in\Omega\big)$. Does this imply $\lim_\limits{t\rightarrow0}x(t,\omega)=0$ for almost all $\omega\in\Omega$? What if we assume $\lim_\limits{t\rightarrow0}x(t,\omega)=0$ in probability?

Comment: This is very closely related to your questions on math.stackexchange.com: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2801027/does-every-fast-enough-sequence-convergence-almost-surely-imply-convergence-almo and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800921/does-every-subsequence-convergence-almost-surely-imply-convergence-almost-surely

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: Yes it is. I hope I have more luck getting an answer here as I have not received any response there. Do you have any idea regarding the questions?

Comment: This isn't cool. You only posted there 4 hours ago. At the very least, you should indicate on your post that this is a cross-posting. Also, you should wait longer before cross-posting.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: I have now indicated as much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A counterexample for all of your questions is as follows. Let $\Omega$ be $[0,1)$, with probability measure $\mathbb P$ being Lebesgue measure. Set $x(t,\omega)=1$ if the fractional part of $1/t$ is $\omega$ and 0 otherwise.

This is a version of the standard example satisfying convergence in probability, but not pointwise.

Comment: Since you [clearly indicated](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301507/does-sequence-almost-sure-convergence-imply-almost-sure-convergence#comment750639_301507) a preference to avoid rapid-fire cross-posting, maybe it would be better to move this counterexample to the MSE question(s) you found?

Comment: Thank you very much, Anthony. +1 If you want to do as @LSpice says, I have no objection.  Just let me know your preference.

Comment: Anthony, this question is actually posed in service of my other question https://mathoverflow.net/q/300557/32660. I have proved the convergence in probability https://mathoverflow.net/a/300960/32660 but am not able to prove the point-wise convergence. Would you be interested in taking a look at it? Thank you.